# Sending value on Button click from UIView to its superview's superview(UIViewController) -iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I have a ViewController called `HomeViewController`. Its subview is `ActivityView` (UIView). ActivityView's subview is `ActivityCard` (UIView). In ActivityCard, I have a button called Enter. On it's click I need to send the values of all textfields from ActivityCard xib to HomeViewController and call an API from there. I have never worked with xib's before so unable to manage this scenario. Any help would greatly be appreciated!

EDIT:

ActivityCard.h

```
@interface ActivityCard : UIView


- (IBAction)actionEnterClick:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblActivityCount;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *enterButton;

@end
```

ActivityView.h

```
@interface ActivityView : UIView

@property (strong) ActivityCard *card;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet iCarousel *carousel;

@end
```

ActivityView.m

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(__unused iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
if (view == nil)
    {
        _card = (ActivityCard*) [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ActivityCard" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

        _card.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 280.0, 350.0);
        _card.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
        view = _card;
    }
    return view;
}
```

HomeViewController.h

```
@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong) ActivityView *viewActivity;

@end
```

HomeViewController.m

```
_viewActivity = (ActivityView*) [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ActivityView" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    _viewActivity.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, _viewContainer.frame.size.width, _viewContainer.frame.size.height);
    [_viewActivity updateActivityUI];

    for (UIView *child in _viewContainer.subviews) {
        [child removeFromSuperview];
    }
    [_viewContainer addSubview:_viewActivity];

    [_viewActivity.card.enterButton addTarget:self action:@selector(enterButtonDidTouch) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [_viewActivity.card.lblActivityCount setText:@"11"];
```

This code has been written when we need to load the ActivityView on a button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have many ways to do it, i will show you a way which i think it's the easiest way.

- Create a `property` of `Enter Button` and `property` for all your textfields in `ActivityCard.h`
- In `HomeViewController` add action for your `Enter Button` by using my code below.

  ```
  [self.activityView.cardView enterButton addTarget:self action:@selector(enterButtonDidTouch) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  ```
- Create a method in `HomeViewController.m` name `enterButtonDidTouch`

  ```
  - (void)enterButtonDidTouch {
      NSString *textOfTextField1 = self.activityView.activityCard.textField1.text;
      // With the same way you can get others text of text fields and use them
  }
  ```

Comment: The method somehow isn't getting called. Anything that I might be missing?

Comment: When I try to set label text from HomeViewController to ActivityCard, it isn't setting value properly. I tried : [_viewActivity.card.lblActivityCount setText:@"11"];

Comment: As i see, you did right way. Can you show me how you implement them? @Dia

Comment: I have edited my question and put all the code there

Comment: As i guess, you have more than 1 ActivityCard. With this situation, you should create `delegate` for `ActivityCard`.

Comment: Yes there are multiple ActivityCards. How to create delegates for this type of hierarchy?

Comment: First, tell me what do you want when write `[_viewActivity.card.lblActivityCount setText:@"11"];`

Comment: setting a label of activity card xib to 11